# Auth with cookie - codeIgniter Http angular in ionic 3

Tags: angular, codeigniter, cookies

i have problem to sent POST/get request to serve.
if i use postman chrome extension it work fine
but when i use angular Http (not httpclient) in ionic
it give errors 
first one is : allow cross origin ==> this done using .htaccess
this one i dont find solution : i use codeIgniter for backend (client buy the code from codecanyon), so there is ci_session cookie, and angular http dont handle that (that what i know- yeh there is other ways for that but i dont understand)
and this is error i get

```js
    Request URL:http://kalaatmgouna.com/endpoint/appusers/login/
Request Method:POST
Status Code:403 Forbidden
Remote Address:198.54.126.89:80
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
Response Headers
view source
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Content-Length:43
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Tue, 24 Oct 2017 20:28:29 GMT
Expires:Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache
Set-Cookie:ci_session=c8873af6f63764f3bfbf80e8c0a43b3659852053; expires=Tue, 24-Oct-2017 22:28:30 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; HttpOnly
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.6.31
Request Headers
view source
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,ar;q=0.2
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:86
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
DNT:1
Host:kalaatmgouna.com
Origin:http://localhost:8100
Referer:http://localhost:8100/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Mobile Safari/537.36
Form Data
view source
view URL encoded
{
  "X-API-KEY": "testkey",
  "email": "test@email.xyz",
  "password": "********"
}:
```

Answer (score 0):

status code: 403, need to check your server side as it's rejecting your request. cors is fine.

Comment: i use chrome://inspect to see console of webview of my app in real device and it show the same error.

Comment: i will test with this extention and then i will post the news. thanks

Comment: 403 errors are almost always caused by issues where you're trying to access something that you don't have access to.

Comment: yeh you are right, becuase angular dont handle cookie so i need solution to get cookie,

Comment: so decide to rebuild every thing with laravel and use jwt auth for that

Answer (score 0):

Auth API in angular you need to work with JWT Auth